# creating new class from existing class: inheritance or partial classes?

Tags: c#

I have a class that defines an object like this:

```
public class MyClass{

   public int TheInt { get; set; }

   public void SomeMethod() { ... }
}
```

Actually, there are several more properties and methods. Now I want to create a new class `MyEnhancedClass` that has all the properties and methods of `MyClass` and that also has 2 methods and 4 properties of its own.

For now, my code has two distinct classes that look very similar; I'm looking to refactor these classes and I'm wondering about partial classes and inheritance. What the best way to do this? Inheritance or partial classes? I know this is a basic OOP question but please bear with me.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Is `MyEnhancedClass` a kind of `MyClass`? What is the relationship between them (never mind that they share some properties)? Could the shared properties be thought of as a particular, separate object?

Comment: There is a good primer on the topic of inheritance here: http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/CSharp/lesson08

Comment: You can use inheritance. Show c# documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: @Oded: No, I want the shared properties to be available in both and have the new properties/methods only in the Extended objects. Should I use partial classes or inheritance?

Comment: I knew people will immediately answer with inheritance, even if they have no idea of how the classes relate to each other, if at all. :(

Comment: It depends on what you are modelling. Inheritance can be used to do this, but it may not be a good way to model your objects.

Comment: @Oded, he said "MyEnhancedClass that has all the properties and methods of MyClass and that also has 2 methods". That is inheritance.

Comment: @adalPaRi - To a man with a hammer... Inheritance should model "is a" relationship. That two different objects share the subset of properties and methods (as far as their interface is concerned) does not mean that one is a specialization of the other. It might mean it, it might not.

Comment: @Oded I'd even go further and not say "is a" but rather "behaves like a" as the only indicator for possible inheritance. Remember Uncle Bob's example of "Square is a Rectangle" where a square is a rectangle but it shouldn't be modeled that way because it essentially behaves differently?

Comment: @DennisTraub - Absolutely. Good point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you're talking about inheritance. To inherit one class from another you use the following notation in C#:

```
public class MyExtendedClass : MyClass
{
    // custom code
}
```

**Update:** Even though inheritance might not be the best solution in every case (see Oded's comments below), partial classes should be avoided because they would be even worse. They are not part of the language but syntactic sugar that encourages the introduction of various code smells.

Comment: No favouring of [composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)?

Comment: I would favour composition over inheritance, but the simplest solution to OP's question is inheritance.

Comment: Sure it is a simple, obvious looking solution, but without knowing more about the problem, how do you know it is the _right_ solution?

Comment: I didn't say it is the right or the only solution. It's just the simplest that came to my mind. I'm absolutely aware of the problems that inheritance creates. Nevertheless inheritance is a way to answer OP's question.

Comment: @Oded: and partial classes? Are those any good for what I'm looking to do?

Comment: @frenchie - Partial classes will still compile to a single class. The questions I had about what you are modelling and the relationship between the classes are what you need to consider in order to decide if inheritance or some other mechanism is right (perhaps you _shouldn't_ share these?).

Comment: @Oded: from the looks of my code, it loos like inheritance is better. I've used composition a lot in my code because I basically have a lot of "has-a" relationships so I became familiar with the pattern. For this case, that familiar pattern felt weird and I think I was looking for inheritance, which so far I've only read about but never needed to implement. Thanks for your suggestion to consider the relationship.

Comment: @frenchie - Sure, if that's the case. I was just weary of jumping to  inheritance as an answer without considering other options (extension methods and composition being two options).

Answer (score 2):

```
public class MyEnhancedClass : MyClass {

 public override void SomeMethod() { ... }    

 // other functions here

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Partial classes allow classes to be spanned across several files.  Eg, a partial definition in one file, and the rest in another file.

Inheritance allows additional functionality to be added to an existing class.  The class inheriting a parent can add additional functions, properties or override parent methods (provided parent allows this) to expand functionality.

From the situation you have described, the later is probably the better option.

```
public class ChildOfMyClass : MyClass {
    public string TheString{get{return "Number : " + TheInt;}}

    public void Foo() {
    }
}
```

`ChildOfMyClass` will have access to the functions and properties of `MyClass`.